# What is causing these two Facebook users to receive different results when extending a page access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an app for which User A (me) and User B (client) are both admins. In addition, both users are admins on the page account as well. When I (as user A):

1. go to the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/v2/)
2. select the appropriate app
3. select page token
4. select the appropriate permissions (email, manage_pages, pages_show_list, ads_management)
5. copy generated token

I can then go to the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/) and paste it in to see that my new page token will expire in ~1 hour. Clicking on "Extend Access Token" gives me a new token and says "This new long-lived access token will never expire". Debugging this new token gives me an expiration date of "Never".

If User B follows these same steps (confirmed with me watching), after clicking on "Extend Access Token" the new token has an expiration date of 2 months.

The information I've found from various sources has said that the only requirement for a forever token is that the user is both a page and app admin which is satisfied here. What else would be causing User B to not receive forever tokens?